# How to detect and Modify robots.txt inside Magento

Tags: robots.txt

How do I modify and ensure that the magento site has robots.txt please?

I am checking if the site has robots.txt as it is being flagged by our SEo tool . see screenshot - http://prntscr.com/k07bvl

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using magento 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Configure Magento for generating robots.txt
To generate a `robots.txt` file, use the following steps:

Login in your Magento admin backend Select

1. Store -> Configuration
2. Select General -> Design
3. Select the dropdown Search Engine Robots.
4. Select the default storefront or one you want to create a robots.txt

**For Default Robots, use one of the available options:**

`INDEX, FOLLOW`: Tell crawlers to index the site and to keep doing this periodically.

`NOINDEX, FOLLOW`: Tell crawlers not to index the site but to check for changes of this policy periodically.

`INDEX, NOFOLLOW`: Tell crawlers to index the shop just once and don’t check for changes periodically.

`NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW`: Tell crawlers not to index the shop and don’t check for changes periodically.

After this is done, click the Reset to Default button to add the default `robots.txt` instructions to the custom instructions field.

You can now add your custom instructions to the default. After editing, click the Save Config button to save your `robots.txt` file to disk.